# Как добавить всем дивам на странице один класс через javascript?

Tags: javascript

Как можно всем дивам на странице (кроме дивов с определенными классами и id) добавить один класс через javascript? Например, при клике на определенную кнопку, или сразу при загрузке страницы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используем псевдокласс [:not()](http://htmlbook.ru/css/not).

```
var blurElems = document.querySelectorAll('body *:not(.my_modal)');
for(var i = 0; i < blurElems.length; i++){
    blurElems[i].className += " blur_class";
}
```

Всем элементам, у которых нет класса "my_modal", добавляем класс "blur_class".

**UPD** Кстати, [есть методы className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList), которые позволяют гораздо проще управлять классами: add(), remove(), toggle() и contains(), но только нужно учитывать, что в старых браузерах может и не работать.

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, не за что. Дополнил кое-что в ответе.

Comment: У меня ещё вопрос небольшой. А как потом также в цикле удалить добавленные классы? Чтобы снять размытие. Я делаю className -= " blur_class", но у всех дивов удаляются все классы, а не один.

Comment: @Виктор Павлов,



или же

    for(var i = 0; i < blurElems.length; i++){
        blurElems[i].classList.remove('blur_class'); 
    }